# How to passing final List<File> keepImage = [] to next page

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

How to passing the list of image to next page i try to declare at the top of code and do like this but it said

```
  PostView({File? keepImage}) : this.keepImage = keepImage ?? [];
```

'keepImage' isn't a field in the enclosing class.
Try correcting the name to match an existing field, or defining a field named

i have keep image into

```
final List<File> keepImage = [];
```

and here is pick image function

```
  Future<void> chooseImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      keepImage.add(File(pickedFile!.path));
    });
    if (pickedFile?.path == null) retrieveLostData();
  }

  Future<void> retrieveLostData() async {
    final LostData response = await picker.getLostData();
    if (response.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    if (response.file != null) {
      setState(() {
        keepImage.add(File(response.file!.path));
      });
    } else {
      print(response.file);
    }
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this.

The easiest is using `shared preferences` to store the image url in cache and so you can retrieve it wherever you want. Another is using arguments, when navigating to the other page, pass the id of this image for it.

Comment: i was try this and it's work :)

final List<File> keepImage = [];
    
    class PostView extends StatefulWidget {
      PostView({
        Key? key,
        @required File? keepImage,
      }) : super(key: key);